# Collection of python dictionaries into sqlite3

Tags: python, dictionary, sqlite

The scenario:

1. A table in SQLite3 database posesses 14 columns.
2. 15 dictionaries with a varying amount of keys (10-14).
3. Each key (the column in the table) has a `list` value with 400 elements exactly i.e. element 5 of each `list` value would be in row 5.

I need to insert the data within these dictionaries into the table mentioned, taking into account the fact that some dictionaries will not be using all 14 columns in the table.

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is already sql-safe and every dict's keys are enough to insert a row:

```
import sqlite3
from itertools import izip, repeat

conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.sqlite3')
table_name = 'test'
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Create test table.
cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {}'.format(table_name));
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE {} (a1 integer, a2 integer, a3 integer)'.format(table_name));
conn.commit()

my_dicts = [
    { 'a1': repeat(1, 5), 'a2': repeat(2, 5), 'a3': repeat(3, 5) },
    { 'a2': repeat(4, 2) },
    { 'a3': repeat(7, 7) },
]

for my_dict in my_dicts:
    # Key <=> Items order has to be preserved.
    # .keys() and .values() not used to be sure
    # the order is preserved.
    keys = []
    items = []
    for k, v in my_dict.iteritems():
        keys.append(k)
        items.append(v)

    sql = "INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ({})".format(table_name, ','.join(keys), ','.join(repeat('?', len(keys))))
    cursor.executemany(sql, izip(*items))
    conn.commit()

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM {}'.format(table_name));
conn.commit()

>>> print cursor.fetchall()
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (None, 4, None), (None, 4, None), (None, None, 7), (None, None, 7), (None, None, 7), (None, None, 7), (None, None, 7), (None, None, 7), (None, None, 7)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this and receive: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_func.py", line 75, in <module>
    cursor.executemany(sql, izip(*items))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.`

Comment: Could you give a sample of your data and the sql to create your table?

Comment: It's created in the Python script using cursor.execute(). I have verified that database and table are created. It possesses `id` as the primary key, and then columns of integer/text. In terms of the data, it's retrieved from a CSV file using `pandas.read_csv()`. Example dictionary would be: `my_dict.get('one')... [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,...,400]`. Again, I have verified the dictionaries after creation.

Comment: Are you assuming the issue is with the data and not the SQL formatting?

Comment: Added example, could you confirm my data is in the same format as yours?

Comment: Yes, it looks identical to the data I'm dealing with. I will triple-check my data today as this obviously works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Kroolik - Found the problem now. The integer which I was inserting into the database was numpy.int64 which can't, apparently, be inserted into sqlite3. I solved this by looping the list, converting each one to `int` using `tolist()`, and creating a new list. Works! Thanks for your help!